# Functions Overloading

Tags: haskell, overloading, typeclass

I am working on my assignment for Funtional Programming.

Task:

> We introduce the typeclass  **NewTypeClass** ​​in order to change the
>   behavior of the function **f** by overloading function f for different
>   types.

Given are:

```
class (Eq a, Ord a, Show a, Num a) => NewTypeClass a where
  f :: a -> a
```

where `f` is a factorial function:

```
f n
  | n == 0 = 1
  | elseways = n * f (n-1) 
where elseways = True
```

One of the types is Int. I have to make type Int Instance of the Typeclass NewTypeClass so that if I give argument the function f returns result like this:

```
f   5         ->>             Error: Unresolved overloading
f ( 5 :: Int) ->>             120
f (-5 :: Int) ->> ... ->> ... Non regular termination.
```

What I have done:

```
instance NewTypeClass Int where
    f n
      | n == 0 = 1
      | elseways = n * f (n-1) 
    where elseways = True
```

My outputs:

```
*Main> f 5
120

*Main> f (5::Int)
120

*Main> f (-5 :: Int)
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

Since when I call `f 5` get back the result `120` that means that I did not overload the function `f` properly. Did I not understand something properly or am I making a mistake somewhere in my code?

Edit:

```
*Main> :set +t
*Main> f 5 
120
it :: NewTypeClass a => a
*Main> f (5::Int)
120
it :: Int
*Main> f (-5 :: Int)
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

Comment: `| else = n * f (n-1) where else = True` looks like a syntax error to me.

Comment: Why is there a type class here?  That makes no sense.

Comment: please run `:set +t` command in your GHCi, then repeat all commands and show us the types it reports together with the values it produces.

Comment: @WillNess I'm pretty sure this isn't in ghci.  "unresolved overloading" isn't a ghc error message.

Comment: @melpomene edited

Comment: @Carl ah, thanks. I thought maybe they edited the responses. if so, could the OP please specify the environment they are running this in? Maybe include a link to live code at tio.run or something?

Comment: @WillNess thanks for the hint. I was testing this in GHCi and my university uses Hugs. I tested it now on hugs and it indeed gives  Unresolved overloading error, should I delete my question now or just post an answer?

Comment: @Carl the assignment doesn't seem to specify exact error messages as produced by ghci. Why would it? "Non regular termination" isn't an exact ghci error message either and it's OK. The objective seems to be to produce a message that would indicate unresolved overloading.

Comment: @n.m. my University uses Hugs to compile our code so my code should work as intended

Comment: so do you have a question? I have a question: what version GHCi were you using? :) it seems mighty polymorphic, [tio](https://tio.run/##VY0xD4IwEIX3/oo3OICRRAYXkrIYBxcc5A9c8AzEUrGFNCT@99oSQ/SWl3v3vXct2Qcr5X2jyFokpxdoh4u5Rbm2Txe1mnpQClmiYlfPAx8XmOBaNiyAO4oirFkJEqLTdiTd8D981uOKx4BeFHhDQ0rsIZGvFivLjmYbTI1toBOd5Sm@9zhL1S9Xm4mF6KkLdRhMF95tQvDg/Qc) can't run your code.

Comment: @Will Ness I don't have a question I think it is clear to me now, thanks! I am using version 8.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `f 5` does give **Uresloved Overloading ERROR** in Hugs but in GHCi it doesn't.We can see

```
*Main> :set +t
*Main> f 5 
120
it :: NewTypeClass a => a
```

here that it is indeed overloaded